# How to import and use SDWebImage in swift xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, sdwebimage

Im new to `Swift` and now making a project that includes showing many photos from the web and I understand that I need to use `SDWebImage`. 
I saw related questions here and in other places but all are in `Objective-C` syntax and not working for me.

What I did till now:

1. I downloaded the zip from GitHub
2. Copied `SDWebImage` folder to my folder
3. Tried all possible combinations for `import`

`#import <"SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h">`

`import SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h`

etc..

Can someone please help me import it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, you need configure `Bridging Header`, it is described [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift). Use the following:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

This will import `Objective-C` code to `Swift` code

Secondly, just use it, like:

```
self.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(self.imageURL)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you already have a Bridging header and only need to organize your imports. Since you copied the source files directly into your project without using cocoapods or Carthage you do the import like this:

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0 code**

```
import SDWebImage

let url = URL.init(string: "https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/zelda/images/b/b1/Link_%28SSB_3DS_%26_Wii_U%29.png")

  imagelogo.sd_setImage(with: url , placeholderImage: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift 5.1 simply import the SdWebimage and use extenion

extension UIImageView{

```
func downloadImage(url : String, placeHolder : UIImage?) throws{
    if let url = URL(string: url){
        self.sd_imageIndicator?.startAnimatingIndicator()
        self.sd_setImage(with: url) { (image, err, type, url) in

            if err != nil{
                    self.sd_imageIndicator?.stopAnimatingIndicator()
                    print("Failed to download image")
                }
                self.sd_imageIndicator?.stopAnimatingIndicator()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way it worked for me (using mac os 10.11.4 and ios 9.3) was this:

1. download and unpack framework from link: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/releases/download/3.6/SDWebImage-3.6.framework.zip:
2. drag that framework into x-code project and check option: Copy items if needed (In project navigator you should now see suitcase icon containing a folder with .h files)
3. create new bridging header file: cmd+n -> file -> new -> file... and select "header" template icon
4. open that file, write line (just above #endif:) #import  < SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h > (this is path of one of header files from framework)
5. the most important step from @Azat answer above, is to connect the file you just made with project, in build settings:

   - select project name (blue icon in Project navigator)
   - select "Build Settings" on your right start to type "Bridging header..." and when you have row containing "Objective-C Bridging header"
   - press twice in empty field in that row (window pops-up), and drag bridging header file from Project navigator into that window.

     6. hopefully now you can use library methods as: imageView.setImageWithUrl(url, placeholderImage:)